# How does picture-sharing iOS apps handle memory when scrolling down in thumbnails?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm currently working on a picture-sharing app on iOS, and my developer is struggling mightily with managing memory. I would really appreciate some help.

Take this "user feeds" module, my developer can't design a scroller that maintains a smooth scroll unless much of the thumbnails are preloaded before scrolling starts. This expectedly makes the initial loading experience much longer than desired. He used server-side compression which further compresses IPhone images (originals were around 2mb) that were already compressed to 200kb on the iOS side down to around 20kb. The end result is a highly blurry low-quality thumbnail, especially displayed at the size seen in the video.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76154448/Scrolling%20Down%20Only%20Works%20With%20Highly%20Compressed%20Thumbnails%20and%20Needs%20Pre-loading%20to%20Ensure%20Smooth%20Scrolling.mp4

He originally just used a cropped version of the underlying image as the "thumbnail," but with each picture being 200kb, 10 "thumbnails" loaded is already 2MB of memory used. Another 2MB is being used on thumbnails of user avatars, since those were not yet compressed by the server. We designed the feed, like many other picture apps, so that more images can be loaded by scrolling down.

My questions are this:

1. What is a good technique to do server side compression of thumbnails without quality loss? How does an app like Streamzoo do this?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76154448/Smooth%20Scrolling%20with%20Streamzoo.mp4

1. What is a good technique for managing the increase in live bytes? How do picture apps like Pic Collage manage to show up to 200 thumbnails while seemingly keeping every image cached without crashing?

Any responses are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

He's probably creating all `UIImageView`s once the server responds. He could use `UICollectionView` to lazy load views, so only a few of them would be on memory on the same time.

I wrote an article about performance tips and tricks, and this one [is covered there](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#lazyviews).

Comment: Marcelo, thanks a lot for your quick response. What do you think is the maximum memory that should be used at any given time for iPhone 4/4S/5? My developer says up to 12MB is already crashing the app. However, I distinctly remember that even 3GS could handle upwards 20MB when it had only 128MB in RAM. Thanks again.